# Searching multiple fields with Lucene

Tags: java, search, lucene

I'm having some trouble with a search I'm trying to implement.  I need for a user to be able to enter a search query into a web interface and for the back-end Java to search for the query in a number of fields.  An example of this might be best:

Say I have a List containing "Person" objects.  Say each object holds two String fields about the person:

```
FirstName:  Jack
Surname:    Smith

FirstName   Mary
Surname:    Jackson
```

If a user enters, "jack", I need the search to match both objects, the first on Surname, and the second on FirstName.

I've been looking at using a MultiFieldQueryParser but can't get the fields set up right.  Any help on this or pointing to a good tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MultiFieldQueryParser` is what you want, as you say.

Make sure:

- The field names are always used consistently
- The same `Analyzer` is used on both  fields, and also on the query parser
- You won't find partial words by default, so if you search for `jack` you won't find `jackson`. (You can search for `jack*` in that case.)

Regarding field name, I always set up an `enum` for my field names, then use e.g. `MyFieldEnum.firstname.name()` when passing field names to Lucene, so that if I make a spelling mistake the compiler can catch it, and it's also a good place to put Javadoc so you can see what the fields are for, and also a place where you can see the complete list of fields you wish to support in your Lucene documents.

Comment: So, when adding people to the index, i can put:  document.add(new Field("FirstName" ... );  within a for loop and it should be ok?

Comment: That's right. Make sure the field is "indexed" (= searchable), i.e. pass this to the constructor of `Field`: http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_0/api/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html#TOKENIZED